# Convergence properties in dense subsets of $\omega^*$

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

The space $\omega^*$, the remainder of the Cech-Stone compactification of the integers, fails to have all convergence-type properties known to me.

1. [Sequentiality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347835/a-variant-of-the-moore-mrowka-problem/396572#396572). (As a matter of fact $\omega^*$ does not even have any convergence sequences, because every infinite closed subset of $\omega^*$ has cardinality $2^\mathfrak{c}$).
2. [Pseudoradiality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347835/a-variant-of-the-moore-mrowka-problem/396572#396572). (Every infinite compact pseudoradial space must contain a convergent sequence).
3. Countable tightness (As proved by Kunen, $\omega^*$ even contains points which are not accumulation points of every countable subset of $\omega^*$).
4. The "weak Whyburn property" (that means, for every non-closed $A \subset X$ there is $x \in \overline{A} \setminus A$ and $B \subset A$ such that $\overline{B} \setminus B=\{x\}$. Note that every compact weakly Whyburn space must contain a convergent sequence).
5. [Discrete generability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330892/is-there-a-lindelof-p-space-which-is-not-discretely-generated). That follows from Proposition 2.4 of:

*Tkachuk, V. V.; Wilson, R. G.*, [**Box products are often discretely generated**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2011.09.004), Topology Appl. 159, No. 1, 272-278 (2012). [ZBL1236.54005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1236.54005).

or from the fact that $\omega^*$ contains a point which is in an accumulation point of a countable set, but not an accumulation point of any countable discrete set (see Theorem 4.4.1 in Jan van Mill's article in the Handbook of set-theoretic topology).

Obviously a dense subset of $\omega^*$ cannot be sequential, but:

QUESTION: Can a dense subset of $\omega^*$ be pseudoradial, countably tight, weakly Whyburn or discretely generated?

Parts of the above question have already been asked in the literature and in the comment section of a question on Mathoverflow (I'll give references below), but I thought it would be nice to have them all in one place.

- [Is there a compact space with no countably generated dense subspace?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122997/is-there-a-compact-space-with-no-countably-generated-dense-subspace/123013#123013) (see the comment section of my answer)
- *Alas, Ofelia T.; Madriz-Mendoza, Maira; Wilson, Richard G.*, [**Some results and examples concerning Whyburn spaces**](http://agt.webs.upv.es/volumes.php?Vol=LAST), Appl. Gen. Topol. 13, No. 1, 11-19 (2012); corrigendum ibid. No. 2, 225-226 (2012). [ZBL1245.54024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1245.54024).  (Question 4.4 even asks whether $\omega^*$ can have a dense Whyburn subspace).

EDIT (22/07/2021): Let me remark that under CH $\omega^*$ has a dense subspace which is radial, Whyburn and discretely generated. It suffices to take the set $D$ of all $P$-points.

Comment: A dense subset of $\omega^*$ cannot be countably tight.  This follows from the fact that if $x$ is any element of $\omega^*$, there is an open subset $U$ of $\omega^*$ whose closure contains $x$ but such that $x$ is not in the closure of any countable subset of $U$.  To get $U$, if $x$ is a P-point, let $U = \omega^* \setminus \{x\}$.  Otherwise, let $U$ be the interior of a zero-set whose boundary contains $x$.

Comment: Very nice. Can you please add your comment as an answer, Anonymous? Just point-out the two non-trivial facts you're using, that $\omega^*$ is an almost P-space and an F-space.

Answer (score 5):

I have been asked to add my comment as an answer, so here it is.  A dense subset of $\omega^*$ cannot be countably tight.  The reason is that if $x$ is any element of $\omega^*$, there is an open subset $U$ of $\omega^*$ whose closure contains $x$ but such that $x$ is not in the closure of any countable subset of $U$, and this property carries over to dense subsets.

To get $U$ consider two cases.  Case 1. If $x$ is a P-point, let $U = \omega^* \setminus \{x\}$. Case 2. If $x$ is not a P-point, it is on the boundary of a zero-set $Z$; let $U = Int_{\omega^*}Z$.  Since zero-sets in $\omega^*$ have dense interiors, $x$ is in the closure of $U$.  It follows from the fact that $\omega^*$ is an  F-space that the $\omega^*$-closure of every countable subset of $U$ is a subset of $U$, and, therefore, does not contain $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Comments from Alan Dow:

(1) under CH the set of P-points is dense and radial even, using $\omega_1$-sequences.

(2) if $D$ is dense and pseudoradial then for every cozero set $C$ of $\omega^*$ the intersection $C\cap D$ is closed in $D$. Say $C=f^{-1}[(0,1]]$; a convergent sequence $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ in $C\cap D$ should have uncountable cofinality, but then there is an $n$ such that $\{\alpha:f(x_\alpha)\ge2^{-n}\}$ is unbounded and hence the limit wound be in $\{x:f(x)\ge2^{-n}\}$.

(3) if there are no P-points then every point of the dense set $D$ is in the boundary of some cozero set $C$, for that $C$ the intersection $C\cap D$ is not closed; hence $D$ is not pseudoradial.

Comment: Thank you, Alan and KP! Very good, so the pseudoradial case is settled. By the way, it looks to me that to get a dense radial subspace in $\omega^*$ you only need MA (actually, $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{c}$).

Comment: Checking that I'm interpreting a consequence of (1) correctly: under CH, there exists an $\omega_1$ sequence of P-points that converges to another P-point?

Comment: @StevenClontz yes: take a P-point $p$ and a local base $\langle C_\alpha:\alpha\in\omega_1\rangle$ that is strictly decreasing ($\alpha<\beta$ implies $C_\beta\subset C_\alpha$); take a P-point $p_\alpha$ in $C_\alpha\setminus C_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha$ and there's your sequence.